# Getting 500 error using ajax in MVC post, working in local

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to save the booking information, i have used ajax to do so.
[image: Ajax code]

[image: Function ajax]

[image: Controller]

[image: My view model]

[image: Getting the below error.]

[image: response text]

[image: html]

The save button is inside the form tag
Even the response text does not contain much information.
It is weird that it is perfectly working in local, but not in hosted place.

Update:
[image: modal]

This is my modal .

```
{BookingID: "0", title: "Test05", start: "30/12/2020 13:00 pm", end: "30/12/2020 15:00 pm", Description: "Test05", …}
```

But the request that is logged is
[image: Time]

The time is getting to default date and time.
Any reason ??

Comment: You will need to add logging to the server side to narrow down where the issue is. Also compare the payload being submitted when it works locally to the payload when it _doesn't_ work.

Comment: How did you install code on server?  There are a number of reasons 1) You are running debug version local and installed release version on server.  Make sure you compiled release version before installing on server.  2) You do not have permission to read/write to file system on server 3)  The roles are set wrong. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: @jdweng I do not think there is any issue in read/write because i am able to so the same operation in different MVC page. Getting this issue in this page only. 
I upload the files to the server and  i double checked the code is deployed.

Comment: The type could be wrong or the format wrong.  You have a DateTime and the string for the DateTime may not parse.  The number format could also be wrong if could is sending period for decimal place and server wants a comma.  The culture on the local server may be set different from the server you are using.

Comment: @jdweng yes seems like somewhere date is getting wrong.

Comment: @jdweng Updated the description. Date and time is being defaulted. Any suggestion to solve this

Comment: Parse using a custom get/set :         private DateTime _start { get; set; }

        public string start
        {
            get {return _start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");}
            set { _start = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }

        }

Answer (score 0):

try to change your ajax call:
instead of

```
var data=  {bookingViewModel:bookingViewModel};
```

use:

```
var data=bookingViewModel; //(or data:bookingViewModel inside of ajax)
```